# De forma inesperada no consigo extraer datos de Yahoo desde R y no se si se debe a algún prolema de Yahoo. Es extraño porque me ha funcionado bien

Tags: rstudio

Esta es la parte que ha dejado de funcionar:

library(quantmod)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(TTR)

library(lubridate)

hoy <- today()
fecha <- hoy - months(20) # Tomamos suficientes datos para poder calcular SMA y ATR
fechainicio <- as.Date(fecha)

getSymbols("XLB", from = fechainicio, src = 'yahoo', periodicity = 'monthly')

Me indica el siguiente código de error:

Error in getSymbols.yahoo(Symbols = "XLB", env = , verbose = FALSE,  :
Unable to import “XLB”.
HTTP error 400.

> 

No he encontrado nada relacionado con este error pero si he leído algún comentario que indicaban algunas veces problemas por parte de Yahoo. Alguien sabría decirme si el error es del código R o de envío de datos por parte de Yahoo?